# What is the best option for columns with huge missing values number?

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest, feature-engineering

I am dealing with my clients dataset.I have inspected data and concluded that some columns have extremely high value of NaNs.Next step is feature importance with random forests.This is the output of my python code

```
for l in newl:
    print (l, pd.isna(dfs[l]).sum())
```

output

```
BNUM_OUT 488
BNUM_IN 488
CALL_OUT_CNT 401
CALL_OUT_SMS 401
CUC_LN_CNT 4880
CUC_COMP_LN_CNT 4880
PROD_CNT_ADO 2825
PROD_CNT_MACRO 2825
REV_BUN_ADO 4908
REV_BUN_MAC 3977
REV_OUT 508
USAGE_GPRS_NAT 401
USAGE_OUT_INT_DUR 401
USAGE_OUT_OFFNET_DUR 401
USAGE_OUT_ONNET_DUR 401
LNE_DAYS_OUT 4
TOPUP_AMT 2263
TOPUP_CNT 1909
```

I have 5000 rows.How to choose which columns should I drop?70 % and more?How is this choice going to influence next random forest step?

Comment: Frankly, your first course of action should be to ask your *client* about the missing values and find out either a.) where the missing values can be found/calculated or b.) why they are missing in the first place. In fact, most of real-world data analysis is actually not machine learning algorithms but rather the (often mind-numbing) task of fixing up the data you're given so that you can, eventually, run something fancy...

Comment: What are these variables? Why are they missing? What is the purpose of your random forest? What questions are you trying to answer?